# Popup box show once in a month to user

Tags: popup

My popup box code works fine on blogger but i want to show this once to each user in 1 month
i tried using cookies but doesn't work , i spent my whole day searching only this but nothing works .
My code is

```
    <!-- Facebook POPUP LikeBox With Timer Code Start -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2  /jquery.js"></script>

<style type='text/css'>
#exepopup{background-color:#fff;position: fixed;top:50%;z-index:9999;display:none;padding:0px;left:50%;border:10px solid rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.7);-webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */-webkit-border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px;-moz-border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px;border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px;width:400px;height:360px;margin-left:-200px;margin-top:0px;overflow:hidden;}#exepopup span{font-size:20px !important;font-weight:bold !important;}#exepopup h1{background:#6d84b4 url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wbOyGFuANTQ/UVF1F4ouC4I/AAAAAAAABiA/RX4jNlICbjM/s1600/aktechz-fb-lock.png) 98% no-repeat;border:1px solid #3b5998 !important;color:#FFFFFF !important;font-size:20px !important;font-weight:700 !important;padding:5px !important;margin:0 !important;font-family:'"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif !important;overflow:hidden !important;}.exepopupdata{font-size:12px !important;font-weight:normal !important;height:265px !important;padding:1px !important;background:#fff !important;border-bottom:2px solid #ddd;overflow:hidden !important;}#exepopupfooter{text-align:left;background:#F2F2F2 !important;height:56px !important;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px !important;overflow:hidden !important;}#exepopupclose{float:right;background-color:#eee !important;border:1px solid #ccc !important;color:#111 !important;font-weight:bold !important;padding:5px 8px 5px 8px !important;text-decoration:none !important;display:inline-block !important;font-family:'"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif !important;outline:none !important;position:relative !important;font-size:18px !important;margin:1px !important;}#exepopupclose:active{top:1px;left:1px;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function()  {
function exepopupfunc() {
var sec = 15
var timer = setInterval(function() {
$("#exepopupfooter span").text(sec--);
if (sec == 0) {
$("#exepopup").fadeOut("slow");
clearInterval(timer);
}
},1000);
var exepopupwindow = jQuery(window).height();
var exepopupdiv = jQuery("#exepopup").height();
var exepopuptop = jQuery(window).scrollTop()+50;
jQuery("#exepopup").css({"top":exepopuptop});}
jQuery(window).fadeIn(exepopupfunc).resize(exepopupfunc)
//alert(jQuery.cookie('sreqshown'));
//var exepopupww = jQuery(window).width();
//var exepopupwww = jQuery("#exepopup").width();
//var exepopupleft = (exepopupww-exepopupwww)/2;
var exepopupleft = 500;
//var exepopupwindow = jQuery(window).height();
//var exepopupdiv = jQuery("#exepopup").height();
//var exepopuptop = (jQuery(window).scrollTop()+exepopupwindow-exepopupdiv) / 2;
jQuery("#exepopup").animate({opacity: "1", left: "0" , left: exepopupleft}, 0).show();
jQuery("#exepopupclose").click(function() {
jQuery("#exepopup").animate({opacity: "0", left: "-5000000"}, 1000).show();});});

</script>
<div id="exepopup">
<h1>Title...</h1>
<div class="exepopupdata">TEXT

TEXT  TEXT
</div>
<div id="exepopupfooter">be patient..</div></div>
<!-- Facebook POPUP LikeBox With Timer Code End -->
```

please post full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use j query cookie plugin with simple if else statement

Comment: Can you please include some example?